# searching through indexes in python

Tags: python, indexing

I was attempting to code out the MIU Formal system in the book Godel, Escher, Bach when I ran into a roadblock.  I am fairly new to computer science and python hence the basics question.

```
derivations = [[0,'MI'],[1,'MII','MIU'],[2,'MIUIU','MIIU','MIII']]
```

I wanted to create derivations the index of sub indexes that have a tree depth number at the beginning of each sub index.  What is the best way to isolate those sub indexes by that integer to run the following strings through a loop.

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the expected output for the given input?

Comment: Hi @user1544819, Stack Overflow questions work best when the question contains all the information necessary to get from the input to the output. It's been a while since I read GEB, so for the benefit of myself and others, you should probably add the derivation rules to your post so that people can test the derivations out themselves.

Comment: i completely understand,  i also am shielding myself from some just solving the whole thing for me.  I specifically wanted just the index issue covered but when i have it finished I will post it up here.  I'm sure there are some great ways to make it more efficient from the way I'm doing it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want something like this:

```
depthDict = {x[0]:x[1:] for x in derivations}
```

Which will take you list of lists and construct a `dict` with the first element as the key. This way you can access you string lists by the **tree depth number** like so:

```
print depthDict [1] # prints ['MII', 'MIU']
```

or

```
for myString in depthDict[3]:
  print myString # prints MII and MIU
```

Comment: this makes a lot of sense.  I have gone over dictionaries and just needed the refresher to have this stare me down as the most useful option.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for specific sub index, you can do it by:

```
>>> sub_indexes = [index for index where index[0] == 1]
>>> sub_indexes
[[1,'MII','MIU']]
```

This will return all sub indexes that have depth of 1. Notice that the result will be a list of all indexes matching to the search criteria, so to get index, you need to do:

```
>>> sub_index = sub_indexes[0]
>>> sub_index
[1, 'MII', 'MIU']]
```

After this, you can just process strings by:

```
depth = sub_index[0]
for mu_string in [item for item in sub_index if hasattr(item, 'count')]:
    new_strings = generate_more_strings(mu_string, depth)
```

where `generate_more_strings(my_string)` will generate variations of a given string.